# How to test keydown keystrokes for a directive on a textbox?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, input, jasmine, keydown

I have a directive that I created that limits the input to be from 1 - 5 and limits the value to only have one decimal point. I am trying to unit test this, but I get a failed test when I try to inject a keydown event--Expected '' to be '1'. So it is as if there were no keys entered for the test. I feel like I am missing something simple. I am new to Angular and unit-testing.

**limited-value.directive.spec.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { LimitedValueDirective } from './limited-value.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-container',
  template: `
  <div>
    <label for="limitedValue">Limited Value</label>
    <input id="limitedValue" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="LimitedValue" appLimitedValue>
  </div>
  `
})
class MyComponent { }
let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

beforeEach(async () => {

  await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [ MyComponent, LimitedValueDirective ],
  }).compileComponents();

  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
  fixture.detectChanges();
 });

 describe('LimitedValueDirective', () => {
  it('should be empty', () => {
    let inputElement:HTMLInputElement = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('input[type=text]');
    expect(inputElement.value).toBe('');
  });

  it('should be one digit', async () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      let inputElement:HTMLInputElement = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('input[type=text]');

      const event = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
        "key": "1"
      });
      inputElement.dispatchEvent(event);

      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(inputElement.value).toBe('1');
    });
  });
});
```

**limited-value.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appLimitedValue]'
})
export class LimitedValueDirective {
  @Input() value: string;
  private regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/^[1-4](\.[0-9])?$|^[1-5]\.$|^5$|^5\.0$/g);
  private el: HTMLInputElement;
  private specialKeys: Array<string> = [
    'Backspace',
    'Tab',
    'End',
    'Home',
    'ArrowLeft',
    'ArrowRight',
    'Del',
    'Delete',
  ];

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    this.el = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if ((this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) || (event.ctrlKey && (event.key == 'v' || event.key == 'c'))) {
      return;
    }

    let current: string = this.elementRef.nativeElement.value;
    const position = this.elementRef.nativeElement.selectionStart;
    const next: string = [
      current.slice(0, position),
      event.key == 'Decimal' ? '.' : event.key,
      current.slice(position),
    ].join('');

    if (next && !String(next).match(this.regex)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 
showing the problem.
You can use [stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com) to create a MRE.

The good part about making a MRE is that you might end up finding the problem yourself ;)
 And in case you don't, people can use the MRE to check where the problem lies.

Comment: You can use 
 [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mtxscj?file=src/testing/test-files.ts)
 as a template to write tests in a stackblitz project! :)

Comment: OK, I forked your template and added my code (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4edtnp?file=src%2Fapp%2Flimited-value.directive.ts,src%2Fapp%2Flimited-value.directive.spec.ts), but I can't get it to run my tests.

Comment: @TimGrunewald you need to add your spec file to `src/testing/test-files.ts` in order to run your tests.

Comment: Right, you'll also have to move the `beforeEach()` into the `describe` block, or else there's an issue with Testbed not instantiating.

Comment: Did the changes mentioned, I still get the "Expected '' to be '1'." failed test.

Answer (score 0):

Tim,

In addition to adding the new spec file to the `test-files.ts` file, it looks like your directive wasn't setting the value of the input.  I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are after, but I made a small adjustment here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gnwbb9?file=src/app/limited-value.directive.spec.ts

The directive now sets the value of the input and I added another test for pressing 6.

Comment: That works for the unit test, but in the actual app that change doubles the number in the textbox when typed.

Comment: interesting.  I was wondering if that was going to be the case.  So we need to figure out why the test isn't waiting long enough for the value of the input to be changed...